# Am I covered to drive my parent's car while visiting?

Tags: usa, insurance, driving-licenses, ohio

I will be visiting my parents in Ohio and plan to drive their car while visiting. Is it common with US auto insurance to allow others to drive their car? If not, how can I get covered for this? I'm on a Dutch driver's license.

Comment: US auto insurance policies *often* cover people who borrow the car with permission for short periods, but to be certain, your parents should read their policy.

Comment: Have you asked your parents if you’d be covered?

Comment: How can we know the details of your parents' insurance?

Comment: Do you own a car and/or have other insurance that includes general liability coverage?  If so, you should also look into the coverage provided by that insurance to see whether it might be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody can answer this question other than your parents insurance policy/company.

Many insurance policies will cover any driver for period of time, especially when that person is a family member - however this is not true for all policies, and the only way to be sure is to check the policy.

Comment: It's worth adding that coverage for permissive drivers will only be in place if a) such coverage is expressly included in the policy, and b) if the permissive driver is licensed and can legally drive the vehicle under the law of the particular state.

Comment: The OP also might have coverage under his own insurance, if any.